# NLog stopped reading my config from app.config

Tags: c#, .net, nlog

My .NET Framework project stopped using my App.config file to configure NLog.
It is no longer using the targets I defined in there.

My App.config file (part of it because of confidentiality):

```
<configSections>
    <section name="nlog" type="NLog.Config.ConfigSectionHandler, NLog" />
</configSections>



<nlog>
    <targets>
        <target name="flowdatabase" type="FlowDatabase" />
        <target name="console" type="Console" />
        <target name="logfile" type="File" fileName="${basedir}/log/debug.nlog" archiveFileName="${basedir}/log/archives/debug.{#####}.nlog" archiveEvery="Day" archiveNumbering="Date" maxArchiveFiles="31" concurrentWrites="true" />
    </targets>

    <rules>
        <logger name="log" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="console, logfile, flowdatabase" />
    </rules>
</nlog>
```

Does anyone see what I am not doing right?

Comment: The basedir may be wrong.

Comment: By default, NLog writes its own internal log file to something like C:\temp\log.txt. If you can find that log, it might have helpful information.